# Pass References to Objects in Arraylist?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I want to create objects for each of the 2 classes and place reference to those objects in an arrayList<> then iterate through the arrayList.

```
    ArrayList<CarbonFootprint> myCarbon = new ArrayList<CarbonFootprint>();
```

How do I implement it? I was able to do without an ArrayList.

```
    CarbonFootprint myCarbon = new Car(150332.00);
    System.out.printf("My Car emits %.2f pounds per year\n",
            myCarbon.getCarbonFootprint());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add them in like so:

```
ArrayList<CarbonFootprint> myCarbonList = new ArrayList<CarbonFootprint>();
CarbonFootprint myCarbon1 = new Car(150332.00);
myCarbonList.add(myCarbon1);
CarbonFootprint myCarbon2 = new Car(13434.00);
myCarbonList.add(myCarbon2);
```

and to display:

```
for (CarbonFootprint footPrint: myCarbonList) {
    System.out.printf("My Car emits %.2f pounds per year\n", footPrint.getCarbonFootprint());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            ArrayList<CarbonFootprint> myCarbonList = new ArrayList<CarbonFootprint>();
    CarbonFootprint myCarbon1 = new Car(150332.00);
    myCarbonList.add(myCarbon1);
    CarbonFootprint myCarbon2 = new Car(13434.00);
    myCarbonList.add(myCarbon2);

    // Enhanced Loop to display the answer.
    for (CarbonFootprint x : myCarbonList) {
        System.out.printf("My Car emits %.2f pounds per year\n",
                myCarbon1.getCarbonFootprint());
        System.out.printf("My House produces %.2f pounds per year\n",
                myCarbon2.getCarbonFootprint());
    }
}
```

My Car emits 118762.28 pounds per year

My House produces 10612.86 pounds per year

My Car emits 118762.28 pounds per year

My House produces 10612.86 pounds per year